# ICE (Internal compiler error) after vcxproj update from vs2013 to vs2015

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2013

"similar questions" do not cover my case.

After switching from VS2013 (v120) to VS2015(v140) result is:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: my_project, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  aSource.cpp
1>d:\my_project\aHeader.h(61): warning C4114: same type qualifier used more than once
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\array(215): warning C4346: 'std::_Is_nothrow_swappable<_Ty>::value': dependent name is not a type
1>  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\array(215): note: prefix with 'typename' to indicate a type
1>  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\array(221): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'std::array<_Ty,_Size>' being compiled
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\array(215): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'value'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\array(216): error C2091: function returns function
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\array(435): error C2988: unrecognizable template declaration/definition
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\array(435): error C2059: syntax error: ')'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\array(442): error C2065: '_Ty': undeclared identifier
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\array(442): error C2065: '_Size': undeclared identifier
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\array(442): error C2923: 'std::array': '_Ty' is not a valid template type argument for parameter '_Ty'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\array(442): error C2975: '_Size': invalid template argument for 'std::array', expected compile-time constant expression
1>  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\array(20): note: see declaration of '_Size'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\array(443): error C2065: '_Ty': undeclared identifier
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\array(443): error C2065: '_Size': undeclared identifier
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\array(443): error C2923: 'std::array': '_Ty' is not a valid template type argument for parameter '_Ty'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\array(443): error C2975: '_Size': invalid template argument for 'std::array', expected compile-time constant expression
1>  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\array(20): note: see declaration of '_Size'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\array(444): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '{'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\array(444): error C2447: '{': missing function header (old-style formal list?)
1>  INTERNAL COMPILER ERROR in 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin\CL.exe'
1>      Please choose the Technical Support command on the Visual C++
1>      Help menu, or open the Technical Support help file for more information
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Notes:

- no Optimization (/Od)
- same issue also for VS2017(v141) and VS2019(v142)
- I have something in mind, that this project was also problematic to compile without VS2013-update5, but thats a real dangerous memory. But maybe it rings someone elses bell?
- Upgrade is necessary because we want to use MongoDB, which latest cxx-driver does not support VS2013

**EDIT:** Content of `aHeader.h`

```
#ifndef AINTERFACE_H
#define AINTERFACE_H 1

typedef int result;

#define IRESULT         result
#define IFUNCTION       virtual IRESULT
#define IIN(X)          X const&
#define IOUT(X)         X&
#define FUNCSPEC_IFACE  noexcept = 0
#define FUNCSPEC_IMPL   noexcept
#define ISUCCESS        0

class aInterface {
public:

    aInterface(IIN(char const* const) name)
        : iface_name_(name) {}

    IFUNCTION iface_name(IOUT(char const*) target)  FUNCSPEC_IFACE;

protected:

    char const*const    iface_name_;
};

#define IFACE_FUNCTIONS_DEFAULT                                         \
            IFUNCTION iface_name(IOUT(char const*) target) FUNCSPEC_IMPL\
                { target = aInterface::iface_name_; return ISUCCESS; }

#define IFACE_DEFAULT(NAME)                                         \
                    IFACE_FUNCTIONS_DEFAULT                         \
                    public: NAME() : aInterface(str(NAME))


#endif
```

Afaik this is the basic interface to implement CRTP

sidenote:

```
#define str_hlp(arg) #arg
#define strnz(arg) str_hlp(arg)
#define strz(arg) str_hlp(arg) "\0"
#define str(arg) strz(arg)
```

Thanks

Comment: It looks like something in your code is massively confusing the compiler. The content of "aHeader.h" is probably relevant.

Comment: Apparently you have some "interesting" type as the template parameter to `std::array`. Apply `remove_cv` on it. Or maybe expand your question with what is your `array` parameter.

Comment: Check also for preprocessor macros that aren't ALL_CAPS. One might have terrible to the compiler code by, for example, `#define array something`

Comment: @Alex Guteniev what is `remove_cv` ?
@Alex Guteniev macro definition seem to be OK. Would that make a difference for the different compilers?

Comment: `remove_cv` is `std::remove_cv` that strips qualifiers. Actually, only `remove_const` is enough. As you posted more code, I have more specific guess, see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During the time of the projects initial development. VS2015 was still not finished and VS2013 does (still) not fully support c++11 standard.

For compatibility reasons, a hack was made at a kinda hidden corner.

```
#if defined( _MSC_VER )/* && (_MSC_VER < insert here version which will support)*/

#  define noexcept  throw()
#  define constexpr const inline

#endif
```

We decided now to change that into

```
#if defined( _MSC_VER ) && (_MSC_VER < 1910)

#  define noexcept  throw()
#  define constexpr const inline

#endif
```

and skip VS2015.

Many thanks